# is there a way we can view the outputs of the failed arm template deployments in portal?

Tags: json, azure, output, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

```
 "outputs": {
      "referenceOutput": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference(variables('identityname'), '2018-11-30', 'Full').identity.clientid]"
      },
      "fullReferenceOutput": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference(variables('identityname'), '2018-11-30', 'Full').properties]"
      },
      "FReferenceOutput": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(variables('identityname'), '2018-11-30', 'Full').properties.identity.clientid]"
      }
    }
```

Is there way where I can quickly parse the ARM Template and view the outputs ?

Answer (score 0):

If a template deployment fails, there are no outputs created for the deployment.  So no possible to view in portal or api.